# import css.map files with wro4j

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, wro4j

I am using wro4j with my spring-mvc application for web resource optimaization.

My page is using twitter bootstrap 3.

After implementing wro4j everything is working fine. but some ui on the page for bootstrap is borken. I feel somehow it is because of bootstrap.css is not getting bootstrap.css.map

wro.xml

```
<!-- CSS resources -->
<group name="bundledCss">
    <css>/views/js/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css</css>
    <css>/views/js/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css</css>
    <css>/views/css/main.css</css>
</group>

<!-- JS resources -->
<group name="bundledJs">                
    <js>/views/js/angular/angular.min.js</js>
    <js>/views/js/angular-resource/angular-resource.js</js>
    <js>/views/js/jquery-2.1.4.js</js>
    <js>/views/js/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js</js>
    <js>/views/js/main.js</js>
</group>
```

wro4j.properties

```
# If true, it is DEVELOPMENT mode, by default this value is true
debug=false
# Default is true
gzipEnabled=true
cacheGzippedContent=true
jmxEnabled=false
# MBean name to be used if JMX is enabled
mbeanName=wro
# Default is 0
cacheUpdatePeriod=100
# Default is 0
modelUpdatePeriod=0
# Default is false.
disableCache=false
# Default is UTF-8
encoding=UTF-8
managerFactoryClassName=ro.isdc.wro.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory
preProcessors=cssUrlRewriting,semicolonAppender,cssMin,jsMin,cssImport,semicolonAppender
uriLocators=servletContext,uri,classpath
```

how to include this bootstrap.css.map file in this config?

Do let me know if you need any other info.

PS: app is working functionally fine. No error in eclipse of browser console.